# How to copy *.rar files listed in a text file to another folder?

Tags: batch-file, copy

I have a text file containing file names and need to copy the files listed in the text file to another folder.

Only one problem is that the file names are without `.rar` at end in the text file.

I am looking for a batch file that can read the text file and copy all the `.rar` files listed in text file to another folder.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your text file looks like this and is called `files.txt`

```
file1
file2
file3
```

and the files in your folder are named file1.rar, file2.rar and file3.rar the following commandline can achieve what you want:

```
for /f "delims=" %f in (files.txt) do copy "%f.rar" "c:\some\other\folder"
```

#### How does this work?

Using the `for /?` details the options available and it's usage:

> FOR /F ["options"] %variable IN (file-set) DO command [command-parameters]
>
> file-set is one or more file names.  Each file is opened, read
>    and processed before going on to the next file in file-set.
>    Processing consists of reading in the file, breaking it up into
>    individual lines of text and then parsing each line into zero or
>    more tokens.  The body of the for loop is then called with the
>    variable value(s) set to the found token string(s).  By default, /F
>    passes the first blank separated token from each line of each file.
>    Blank lines are skipped.

I used the `delims` option to make sure the complete line is read, including any spaces.

> delims=xxx      - specifies a delimiter set.  This replaces the default delimiter set of space and tab.

In this solution the copy command is called for each line in the text file which enables fixing the missing extension and copying it to a new location.

Comment: you don't need a batch file. This will work directly from the commandline. It will work in the folder where the files.txt file is together with the files that needs to be copied.